# Xpath/Css/class search does not work when using protractor

Tags: css, xpath

I am fairly new to using protractor or using automation testing tools. I am trying to click a link on a website. The link or even a button on that page does not have an id tag. So I have tried several ways to click the button or any link on that page:

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('//[@id="navbar"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a')).click()
browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.btn.btn-primary.btn-xlarge')).click()
browser.driver.findElement(by.linkText('Get Started')).click()
```

I have tried many combinations than the ones listed above. Most of the times I get the error, no such element found. Any help is greatly appreciated. Have been struggling on this with no luck.

Comment: please provide the html

Comment: <div class="container-fluid" id="cta">
 <h1>What's in your app?</h1>
 <p>
  Combine a full fledged banking API with the power of your imagination.<br />
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xlarge" href="get-started">Get Started</a>
 </p>
</div>

Comment: The three examples provided in the 1st post are for different elements on the web page. The first example is for a link in the header drop down. The attached code represents two attempts for link in the body. Get Started Button by css style, and by linkText.

Comment: html for the dropdown hyperlink "My apps" am trying to select below. Please let me know if you need more context or html. Hitting a wall every time for something that appears relatively simple. I have used xpath, css, link text, partial link text and class for this operation. None worked

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li class="sign-in dropdown">
                <a href="/login" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="icon icon-user-2 hidden-xs"></i>  
                 User  FLname <i class="icon icon-arrow-65"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/my-apps">My Apps</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
       </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>